# Android Kotlin convert data class into enum class

Tags: android, kotlin, enums

Here `Customer` and `BodyModel` are data classes. I need an inner function at `User`, `toCustomer()`, to convert `User class` into `Customer class`. I am stuck at changing `Boolean type` to `Customer.Type`

Customer Class

```
data class Customer(
    val id: String,
    val bodyModel: BodyModel?,
    val isDrinks : Type
){

enum class Type(val type: String, val value: Boolean) {
        NO("No", false),
        YES("Yes", true)
    }
}
```

BodyModel class

```
data class BodyModel(
    val height: Int?,
    val weight: Int?
)
```

User class

```
data class User(
    val id: String,
    val height: Int?,
    val isDrinks: Boolean?
){

@Ignore
fun toCustomer() = Customer(
    id, 
    BodyModel(height?:-1, -1 ),
    Customer.Type(?????????)
)
```

Comment: `Customer.Type.NO` or `Customer.Type.YES`. But why use an enum for what is essentially a Boolean?

Comment: @Tenfour04,  my server gives `isDrinks` as a `Boolean`. I implemented this at UI in a radioGroup with enum logic. I need to pass `isDrinks` to `Customer.Type.YES or Customer.Type.NO`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it like this:

```
@Ignore
fun toCustomer() = Customer(
    id, 
    BodyModel(height?:-1, -1 ),
    if (isDrinks == true) Customer.Type.YES else Customer.Type.NO
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is a toy example and you want something more general, try this:

```
enum class Type(val type: String, val value: Boolean) {
  NO("No", false),
  YES("Yes", true);

  companion object {
    val map: Map<Boolean, Type> = Type.values().associateBy{it.value}
  }
}
```

and then do this

```
fun toCustomer() = Customer(
    id, 
    BodyModel(height?:-1, -1 ),
    Customer.Type.map[isDrinks]
)
```

Comment: I already had a companion object in Customer class. though your answer is very helpful.